# Animation is lost when view is not displayed (yet) in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a button implemented like so:

```
struct CircleButtonView: View {
    
    init(_ content: Image, tutorial: Bool = false, _ action: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        self.content = content
        self.repetitions = tutorial ? 6.0 : 0.0
        self.action = action        
    }
    
    let content: Image
    var repetitions: CGFloat
    let action: (() -> ())?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            action?()
        }) {
            Circle()
                .fill(.white)
                .shadow(color: Color(hex: 0x000000, alpha: 0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        content
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) // 1:1
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.4)
                            .position(x: proxy.size.width / 2, y: proxy.size.height / 2)
                    }
                )
                .aspectRatio(1 / 1, contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .shake(repetitions: repetitions)
        .animation(repetitions != 0 ? .linear(duration: 1).delay(2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) : .default, value: repetitions)
    }    
}
```

Via the tutorial bool i want to manipulate whether the button animates (an initial shake animation used to explain the button, if the user clicked it once i remove the animation).

This works nicely. However i have to use a "hack", which i dont like and will describe now.

I call the button in some parent view like so:

```
CircleButtonView(Image("flash.selected"), tutorial: <condition for tutorial> && appeared) {
    // vm.boost()
}
.onAppear {
    appeared = true
}
```

As you can see, despite my condition i also have to check wheter the button has appeared. If i would not do that, the animation would be lost ... (this is, as the init block runs and the view did not appear yet, any future calls, where the view appeared, do work perfectly)

As this does not feel right, is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate, SwiftUI needs to observe a before state of the view and an after state.  As you've seen, SwiftUI needs to see the `repetitions` value change from `0` to `6` in order to perform the animation.  Processing the `.onAppear  { }` from the user of `CircleButtonView` is the wrong place.  Put that code inside of `CircleButtonView`.

Make `repetitions` into an `@State private var`.  Don't set it in `init()`.

```
@State private var repetitions = 0
```

In `init()`, store `tutorial` in a local let:

```
self.tutorial = tutorial
```

Then add this `.onAppear` to your `Button`:

```
}
.shake(repetitions: repetitions)
.animation(repetitions != 0 ? .linear(duration: 1).delay(2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) : .default, value: repetitions)
.onAppear {
    repetitions = tutorial ? 6.0 : 0.0
}
```

Comment: How would i stop the animation then.

Comment: Try adding `.onChange(of: tutorial) { _ in repetitions = tutorial ? 6 : 0 }` to the above code.